# Connecting to SoftEther VPN server as client

Tags: c#, vpn

I've been trying to figure out ways to connect to my SoftEther server as a client with no success. I know there are methods of using the third-party application "OpenVPN" to establish a connection, but I'd like to avoid doing so in making a standalone application.

Notably, I've tried using rasdial.exe to do so but also couldn't get a response.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("rasdial.exe", $"{ip} {userName} {pw}")
```

Though SoftEther also requires declaring what "hub" you are connecting to, which may or may not be part of the issue with using rasdial. I'm losing faith in myself, if anyone could provide some help I'd be overjoyed.